# VSTS Load Test : Add server side performance counters(CPU utilization, Private Bytes etc)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, performance-testing

Please let me know how to capture server-side(DB Server, Web Server) performance counters(like CPU utilization, Private Bytes, deadlocks etc.) from VSTS Load test script.

I have added them from 'Manage counter sets' window ,  However they are not captured.  Please help me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Based on the warning, it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As your warning message states, you can not capture this type of metrics when running a load test from a cloud based test.

To achieve what you want you will have to install the test agents on local servers.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/clt-with-private-machines?view=vsts